# Расшифровка исходного кода

Tags: html, flash

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как расшифровать исходный код онлайн трансляции?

Вот зашифрованная ссылка:

```
<param name="flashvars" value="netstreambasepath=http%3A%2F%2Ftv.jampo.com.ua%2Fplay%2Fchannel%2F2x2%2F&amp;id=myplayer&amp;file=2x2&amp;skin=%2Ffiles%2Fjwplayer%2Fblueratio.zip&amp;rtmp.session=eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMzQ3MjE2OTkzLCAic2Vzc2lvbl9pZCI6IjBiMWYxN2E0OTZhMmQ5Yzc3N2Q3ZTBiZDA2NDI4OWU1M2MyYjlhYzUifQ%3D%3D--36dc9df875ed9335d143880543a28fcd7696daba&amp;rtmp.tunneling=false&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;autostart=true&amp;streamer=rtmp%3A%2F%2F109.123.126.90%2Fstream%2F&amp;controlbar.position=over">eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMzQ3MjE2OTkzLCAic2Vzc2lvbl9pZCI6IjBiMWYxN2E0OTZhMmQ5Yzc3N2Q3ZTBiZDA2NDI4OWU1M2MyYjlhYzUifQ
```

Comment: Это не исходный код онлайн трансляции, это hash параметров и Base64 JSON

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте, похоже на base64. Вот ссылка [расшифруйте этот код](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/base64_decode/). Удачи!

Расшифровка:

```
{"user_id":1347216993, "session_id":"0b1f17a496a2d9c777d7e0bd064289e53c2b9ac5"}
```

А если Вам надо чисто ссылку, тогда через функцию в php `urldecode`

Comment: Спасибо вам огромнейшее!!!Это то что нужно!!!

Comment: Обращайтесь, удачи Вам!

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью функция `urldecode` в php

```
<?
echo urldecode("http%3A%2F%2Ftv.jampo.com.ua%2Fplay%2Fchannel%2F2x2%2F&amp;id=myplayer&amp;file=2x2&amp;skin=%2Ffiles%2Fjwplayer%2Fblueratio.zip&amp;rtmp.session=eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMzQ3MjE2OTkzLCAic2Vzc2lvbl9pZCI6IjBiMWYxN2E0OTZhMmQ5Yzc3N2Q3ZTBiZDA2NDI4OWU1M2MyYjlhYzUifQ%3D%3D--36dc9df875ed9335d143880543a28fcd7696daba&amp;rtmp.tunneling=false&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;autostart=true&amp;streamer=rtmp%3A%2F%2F109.123.126.90%2Fstream%2F&amp");

//http://tv.jampo.com.ua/play/channel/2x2/&id=myplayer&file=2x2&skin=/files/jwplayer/blueratio.zip&rtmp.session=eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMzQ3MjE2OTkzLCAic2Vzc2lvbl9pZCI6IjBiMWYxN2E0OTZhMmQ5Yzc3N2Q3ZTBiZDA2NDI4OWU1M2MyYjlhYzUifQ==--36dc9df875ed9335d143880543a28fcd7696daba&rtmp.tunneling=false&stretching=exactfit&autostart=true&streamer=rtmp://109.123.126.90/stream/&
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромнейшее!!!Это то что нужно!!!

Answer (score 1):

[Расшифровка](http://codepad.org/p5Qk845d).

```
<?
$params = 'netstreambasepath=http%3A%2F%2Ftv.jampo.com.ua%2Fplay%2Fchannel%2F2x2%2F&amp;id=myplayer&amp;file=2x2&amp;skin=%2Ffiles%2Fjwplayer%2Fblueratio.zip&amp;rtmp.session=eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMzQ3MjE2OTkzLCAic2Vzc2lvbl9pZCI6IjBiMWYxN2E0OTZhMmQ5Yzc3N2Q3ZTBiZDA2NDI4OWU1M2MyYjlhYzUifQ%3D%3D--36dc9df875ed9335d143880543a28fcd7696daba&amp;rtmp.tunneling=false&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;autostart=true&amp;streamer=rtmp%3A%2F%2F109.123.126.90%2Fstream%2F&amp;controlbar.position=over';
$body = 'eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMzQ3MjE2OTkzLCAic2Vzc2lvbl9pZCI6IjBiMWYxN2E0OTZhMmQ5Yzc3N2Q3ZTBiZDA2NDI4OWU1M2MyYjlhYzUifQ';

$hash = array();
$paramsParts = explode( ';', urldecode( $params ) );

foreach( $paramsParts as $part ) {
   $tmp = explode('=', $part);
   $hash[ $tmp[0] ] = str_replace('&amp', '', $tmp[1]);
}

print_r($hash);
echo "-----------------------\n";
$bodyHash = json_decode( base64_decode($body), true );
print_r($bodyHash);
```